# Notification for new activity goes to deleted account on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Tags: support, notifications, user-accounts

For a while I had an account with the name [bahamut](https://stackexchange.com/users/9291617/bahamut?tab=accounts).

I asked to delete that account, because my English was too broad for understanding. Now it is a little bit better and I made a new account [on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/user966203)

The notifications go to my old account. Is it possible to fix it?

No, I don't want merge the two accounts. Deleting something means for me it's gone. But if there is no other way, I'll try to merge it.

Comment: No, you did not delete your account on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I delete account on unixstackexchange not from askubuntu.

Comment: So you should delete on askubuntu too. Account deletion is per-site.

Answer (score 2):

If you join a site again, after previously deleting your account there, you'll cause a new account to be created for you on that site and associated with all your other Stack Exchange sites. That's by design.

If you're using the app, you won't even be asked to create the new account, it will be created when you post a comment or answer.

So in order to not get notifications, simply don't join the site again.

Comment: I think it is a miunderstandig. I need notification for my new account on askubuntu.

Comment: @user966203 you have no new account. If you tried to create a new account while still having one, it got auto merged into the old account.

Comment: I didn't know that stackexchange is designed that way. How should i.

Comment: @user966203 you shouldn't, that's why you can ask here and get answers. :)

Comment: yeah, and get the first upvote. Just kidding. :D